# Android: FrameLayout weight

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть обыкновенная `FrameLayout`:

```
FrameLayout i1 = new FrameLayout(this);
```

Как задать ей атрибут `android:layout_weight`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается через `LayoutParams`

```
КЛАСС_РОДИТЕСКОГО_КОНТЕЙНЕРА.LayoutParams params = (КЛАСС_РОДИТЕСКОГО_КОНТЕЙНЕРА.LayoutParams) i1.getLayoutParams();
params.weight = 1;
```

---

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.weight = 1;
i1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Родитель моей FrameLayout есть LinearLayout. Задал всё, как Вы сказали. Не работает. `java.lang.ClassCastException: ... LinearLayout.LayoutParams cannot be cast to FrameLayout.LayoutParams...`

Comment: @L'Esperanza, странно. Ну, поменяйте на FrameLayout

Comment: У `FrameLayout` нет конструктора, который может задать атрибут `weight`. Насколько я помню, это делает только `LinearLayout` и `TableLayout`.

Comment: @L'Esperanza, попробуйте обновление ответа

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Я один в один такой код и писал. Ну уж чтоб на 100% удостоверится, скопировал ваш код и заменил на него свой.

Comment: @L'Esperanza, попробуйте сначала тогда добавить ваш FrameLayout  в контейнер, а потом использовать код из ответа

Comment: То же самое. Не меняется ничего.

Comment: Есть много LayoutParams  - ReletiveLayout.LayoutParams, LinearLayout.LayoutParams, MarginLayoutParams и так далее, тысячи их. Вам надо создать LayoutParams родительского контенера - в данном случае FrameLayout, как я вижу. Возможно Вам надо обратить внимание на импорты в файле - возможно у Вас импортировались не те LayoutParams

Comment: @L'Esperanza, вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8569947/3212712) у людей всё работает. Таки да - проверьте импорты и отключите `InstantRun` в студии, если он включён

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а детёнышу родителя (TextView внутри FrameLayout) можно задать LinearLayout.LayoutParams?) Кажется вот тут у меня и вылетало.))

Comment: @L'Esperanza, нет, ему только FrameLayout.LayoutParams